# Redirect Specific URL within Webview - Android

Tags: android, webview

I have a `WebView` within an app that loads a specific url, it's possible however that when using the app the user may be taken/redirected within the web view to another url, for example www.cheese.com, that shouldn't be viewed within the app.
Is it possible to listen for that url (www.cheese.com) within the `WebView`and if it begins to load redirect it to another url before it finishes loading?

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private WebView mWebView;

        mWebView.loadUrl("https://example.com");

        // Enable Javascript
        WebSettings webSettings = mWebView.getSettings();
        webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);

    }
}
```

Comment: Are you trying to say that if url start with (www.cheese.com) then it will redirect to another url?

Comment: Yes, absolutely

Comment: Then you have to use `shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url)` method in that method you can do this.

Comment: Sorry, I've looked at this method but cant work out how I set the url to listen for and, if that starts to load, the url to redirect to?

Comment: I have added answer because `shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url)` method is deprecated in API 24 and the `shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, WebResourceRequest request)`method is added in API 24.

Answer (score 1):

```
    // Load CustomWebviewClient in webview and override shouldOverrideUrlLoading method
    mWebView.setWebViewClient(CustomWebViewClient)



class CustomWebViewClient extends WebViewClient {

    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    @Override
    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
        final Uri uri = Uri.parse(url);
        return handleUri(uri);
    }

    @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.N)
    @Override
    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, WebResourceRequest request) {
        final Uri uri = request.getUrl();
        return handleUri(uri);
    }

    private boolean handleUri(final Uri uri) {
        Log.i(TAG, "Uri =" + uri);
        final String host = uri.getHost();
        final String scheme = uri.getScheme();
        // Based on some condition you need to determine if you are going to load the url 
        // in your web view itself or in a browser. 
        // You can use `host` or `scheme` or any part of the `uri` to decide.

        /* here you can check for that condition for www.cheese.com */
        if (/* any condition */) {
            // Returning false means that you are going to load this url in the webView itself
            return false;
        } else {
            // Returning true means that you need to handle what to do with the url
            // e.g. open web page in a Browser
            final Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, uri);
            startActivity(intent);
            return true;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to use something like this:

```
webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {

            if (url != null && url.startsWith("http://www.cheese.com")) {
                //do what you want here
                return true;
            } else {
                return false;
            }
        }
    });
```